# How can i translate this PHP code to C# asp.net-mvc?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript library that is expecting this from the server but the example is in PHP

```
<?php
/* http://www.example.com/json.php */
$array['E'] =  'Letter E';
 $array['F'] =  'Letter F';
 $array['G'] =  'Letter G';
 $array['selected'] =  'F';
 print json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

so I trying to find how to do the above in c# asp.net-mvc given that C# arrays don't take string keys . .

```
 public JsonResult MyAction()
 {
     return Json(...);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the resulting JSON look like from that PHP code?

If its an object.. you could just return an anonymous object:

```
return Json(new {
    E = "Letter E",
    F = "Letter F",
    // etc...
});
```

If its a key-value pair, you could use a Dictionary:

```
return Json(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "E", "Letter E" },
    { "F", "Letter F" },
    // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using anonymous types:

```
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(
        new
        {
            E = "Letter E",
            F = "Letter F",
            G = "Letter G",
            Selected = "F",
        });
}
```